# Given $A\in M_{2}(\mathbb Z)$ be such that $|A_{ij}(n)|\leq 50$ . prove $|A_{ij}(n)|\leq 50$ for all $n$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A\in M_{2}(\mathbb Z)$ be such that $|A_{ij}(n)|\leq 50$ for all $1 \leq n \leq 10^{50}$.
and all $1\leq i ,j\leq 2$.where $A_{ij}(n)$ denotes the $(i,j)$-th entry of the $2\times 2$ matrix $A^n$.then prove that $|A_{ij}(n)|\leq 50$ for all positive integers n.

I am looking for some hints on this question.

Comment: Hint: How many $2\times 2$ matrices are there all of whose entries are at most $50$ in magnitude? What happens if $A^m=A^n$ for some distinct $1\leq m,n\leq 10^{50}$?

Comment: The number of $2 \times 2$ integer matrices with entries having absolute value at most $50$ is $101^4$. So, noting that $10^{50} > 101^4$, the claim could be easily proven using the pigeonhole principle.

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut Thank you for your hints : By pigeonhole principle we have $A^m = A^n$ for distinct $m,n$ .assuming $m<n$ we have $A^r = A^j$ for $r\geq n+1$ and for some $ j\in \{m,m+1,\ldots n-1\}$.